# Website requests work on desktop browser but not mobile browser using express and react

Tags: reactjs, rest, express, backend, web-frontend

This Problem really blows my mind.

I'm using reactjs as frontend and expressjs as backend, and my website is working just fine when i open it on pc or laptop although when i open from opera or google on my phone, it says failed to fetch.

The issue gets solved when i access the server from my mobile and do the request manually and then coming back to the website it all works fine.

EDIT:
I tried NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED and still nothing also tried rejectUnauthorized = false and also nothing

Comment: This might be SSL related.

Comment: @Owl yeah the error that occurs on the phone browser is ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID